# Xamarin Image Cropping

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to make my own "slider" within Xamarin forms by using images. I have the two images below on top of each other with another image on top as the "handle". As I move the handle along I am wanting to crop the empty and filled images as the handle moves along (while maintaining the aspect ratio of the images). I can get a working version by setting `X` and `Width` values on the respective images as the handle slides along but I am not able to get the aspect ratio to stay the same...as in the images are resized but not cropped. When changing the `Aspect` property to `Aspect.AspectFill` the cropping behaves very oddly. Might be worth mentioning I am setting the size and positioning through the `LayoutBounds` property.

[image: graph fill image]

[image: graph empty image]

Long story short, my question is how can I crop an image (from any direction) on the fly?

XAML for the page the content is put onto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.PageView"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
  <AbsoluteLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="WidgetContent" />
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My data structure is a collection of widgets (WidgetViewModel), which has a collection of images (ImageViewModel) that get added onto the layout. This function adds images into the `WidgetContent` layout:

```
private void BuildImageView(ImageViewModel widgetImage)
{
    widgetImage.PropertyChanged += this.UpdateBounds;

    Image image = new Image()
    {
        BindingContext = widgetImage
    };

    // Set bindings for source
    image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "Source");
    image.SetBinding(Image.AspectProperty, "Aspect");

    // Set the size and bounds and scale to match screen size
    Rectangle bounds = this.ScaleBounds(widgetImage.LayoutBounds);

    // Redefine the value of the x/y positions after scaling
    widgetImage.XPosition = bounds.X;
    widgetImage.YPosition = bounds.Y;
    widgetImage.Width = bounds.Width;
    widgetImage.Height = bounds.Height;

    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(image, bounds);
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(image, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);

    // Add the image to the layout
    this.widgetContent.Children.Add(image);
}
```

This function handles moving the handle and where I am trying to update the fill/empty sizes:

```
private void UpdateHandlePosition(Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle position, Xamarin.Forms.Point touchPoint)
{
    GraphWidget graphWidget = (GraphWidget)this.Widget;

    double newX = position.Left + touchPoint.X;
    double fillWidth = touchPoint.X + this.HandleDown.Width;

    if (newX + this.HandleDown.Width > position.Right)
    {
        newX = position.Right - this.HandleDown.Width;
        fillWidth = position.Width;
    }
    else if (newX < position.Left)
    {
        newX = position.Left;
        fillWidth = 0.1;
    }

    this.HandleDown.XPosition = newX;

    // HERE is my current attempt to resize the image                                                              
    ImageViewModel fillImage = this.Images.ElementAt(1);
    fillImage.Width = fillWidth;
}
```

Comment: Xamarin.Forms or Xamrin.iOS/Android ? Show some code :)

Comment: It is Xamarin.Forms. I'll update the tags.

Comment: can you show some code, too? XMAL and/or code behind that layouts the image :) I'd use #xamarin and #xamarin.forms, becauase I think most answerers are filtering for #xamarin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The view is built dynamically inside an `AbsoluteLayout`. I am simply adding Images to that layout with bindings set for the `Source` and `LayoutBounds` properties. I am also using `AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None` so that I have full control of positioning and size inside the absolute layout.

Comment: Code says more than 1000 words. Could you please add the two important parts of your code, please? It helps people to reproduce your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1000+ words have been added :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125539/discussion-between-butteredtoast-and-sven-michael-stube).